# Three is/are enough?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, numbers

Should I use a singular or plural verb?

I got another dog because apparently three IS not enough.

Or

I got another dog because apparently three ARE not enough.

Comment: Use the word for a small number, usually ten or less. Three are not enough.

Comment: According to 70s television "Eight **Is** Enough". I think this is essentially the same issue as whether the committee *is* having lunch or the committee *are* having lunch.

Comment: The accepted abbreviation for both _three is_ and _three are_ is doubtless _three's_ nowadays. // After a unit usage (or implied), _is_: 'Will you manage 10 miles per day?' ... 'No; eight is enough.' // After a count usage, 'are' can, as far as I see, never be wrong. But a notional 'is' (perhaps for 'owning / having / coping with three is enough' is probably not unacceptable.

Comment: e.g., Thousand is a lucky number; but there are thousands. / His share is three units. Three (units) is his share. I think this way numbers are used in a collective nature.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. Asking questions can help to clarify what is happening:

- Three aren't enough. There aren't enough what? There aren't enough dogs.
- Three isn't enough. What isn't enough? Having only three dogs isn't enough.

In the first case, three (dogs) is the subject of TO BE, hence the plural.
In the second case, (having only) three (dogs) is the subject of TO BE, hence the singular. My suspicion is that which case is more common will depend on the variety of English, as well as the noun in question. Nevertheless, both are definitely in usage, as can be illustrated with another example, where all the following are in usage:

There aren't enough spoons.
Are there enough spoons?
Are 3 spoons enough?
Is this enough spoons?
Is 3 spoons enough?

Comment: You can't (always) 'clarify what is happening' by tinkering with grammar this way. 'Bill meets three ladies'. 'Three dogs are met by Bill.' A transformation may engender a change in verb form.

Comment: I'd agree that 'tinkering' as you put it is more of an initial exploratory approach than a definitive method of systematic analysis. :-) However, there's a difference between what I'm doing and the example you give. What I'm doing is asking questions as a heuristic for helping to identify the subject. In this instance, it helps us uncover some possible ellipses, but it doesn't change the voice of the verb.

Comment: In your example, in contrast, you're switching between active and passive, which is a drastic transformation that comes with several other associated changes, including, of course, the subject of the verb (with which it will need to agree).

Answer (score 1):

I got another dog because apparently three **[dogs] are** not enough. dogs is implied. I would write this.

*OR*

I got another dog because apparently **three is** not enough. I might say this.

English is full of ellipses.

[examples of ellipses](https://www.englishreservoir.com/advanced-english-grammar/ellipsis/)